# Easiest way to develop DNN modules?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

What is the easiest way to develop dot net nuke modules ? I tried VS starter kit, but you have to copy modules to the web server and run them there.

Is it possible to setup the dev environment that you could just hit 'F5' and see/debug your module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install and use DNN Website Starterkit to setup dnn in local development environment, and after that, to create modules, you can use module development templates. There are many module development templates available on web. for example: http://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/

So, by using module development template, you can easily create and debug your module. 
See this like: http://adefwebserver.com/dotnetnukehelp/DNN4_WAP/ for help on same topic

Comment: Where can I get DNN Website Starterkit for DNN 5.5 ?

Comment: DNN Website Starter kit = VS starter kit ?

Comment: go to dotnetnuke.codeplex.com, and click on downloads section. you will notice there is "x.x.x - Visual Studio Starter Kit " always there. that s dnn starter kit for visual studio

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that DNN Website Starter kit = VS starter kit, just different names for same thing.

Comment: Do I need to istall DNN in order to use VS starter kit ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a steep by steep guide for total DNN noob ?

I still don't know everything I need and why.

Comment: http://adefwebserver.com/dotnetnukehelp/

Comment: Easiest way to make a simple module http://www.adefwebserver.com/DotNetNukeHELP/DNN5_HelloWorld/Default.htm