# how to install dotnetnuke on windows 7 IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, installation, iis-7.5, dotnetnuke-5

i want to install dotnetnuke on windows 7 IIS7.5, does any one know how to install dotnetnuke, i have already created the blank website and also have a database, but i dont have any knowledge to install dotnetnuke.

Please revert...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Microsoft Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx).
If you need a development environment, follow this [tutorial](http://www.byteblocks.com/post/2009/11/16/DotnetNuke-Module-Development-Setup-Development-Environment.aspx).

Comment: Although I've checked the link and it's actually working, may be it would be even better for you to refer to the [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018832/easiest-way-to-develop-dnn-modules) here on SO.